# Android - custom marker moves away from its position while zooming

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm just trying to add markers to a map on Android.
I'm using this code founded on the google example

```
    map = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(AREA_C_CENTER)
                                .title("Area c")
                                .snippet("Pubblico")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_red)));
```

The marker is added correctly to the map but when I start to zoom, it loses its position and starts to move away.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something in the center of the screen, don't add a marker, but place an ImageView with layout_gravity="center" in the layout file alongside SupportMapFragment.

Comment: Thanks for the response Maciej Górski, but what i'm trying to achieve is not to place an image in the centre of the screen. What i wanto to do is to place custom pin on the map,that keep the correct position when i zoom

Comment: That is the default behaviour of markers. They don't change positions unless you use setPosition or user moves draggable marker.